# node.js cluster with https

Tags: node.js, express, cluster-computing

I'm using the [cluster npm](http://learnboost.github.com/cluster/) for my node app.

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var app = express.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
});

cluster(app)
 .use(cluster.logger('logs'))
 .use(cluster.stats())
 .use(cluster.pidfiles('pids'))
 .use(cluster.cli())
 .listen(443);
```

But I got the Permission denied when I use port 443. It's working fine if I use another port . Obviously 443 is dedicated to https, so how can I use it for my app ?

Comment: You will have to be root/superuser/admin to bind to lower ports. Can you bind to port 80 fine?

Comment: I cannot bind to 80 either. Hmmm... do you think it's good to run a node.js app as root ?

Comment: You'r right, no pb when running the app as root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default node can't access lower ports (unless you're `root`). Don't be afraid though since any port will do.

The one usually used for development purposes is `8443`:

```
 .listen(8443);
```

Comment: +1 then you can forward 443 to 8443 like so:

sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443

then

sudo iptables-save

Be sure to add those to rc.local